# Outlook 2016: "Network Error" popup on attachment's Save As dialog

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop that displays a "Network Error" pop up whenever the user clicks Save As on an Outlook 2016 attachment. The path in the message is a UNC to her old laptop (which has been recycled). I've tried to search for where Windows/Outlook could be caching this UNC, but I haven't found. Google/Bing searches only seem to turn up the steps for saving attachments in Outlook. Any idea where this is being cached at so I can delete the link?

[image: Network Error Window]

Comment: "tried to search for where Windows/Outlook could be caching this UNC, but I haven't found" Where/how did you search exactly?  Did you search the Registry for occurrences of that path? If the UNC points to an old laptop that's no more, why blank it out (it only adds confusion IMO)?  Is this machine on a domain or stand-alone?

Comment: Sorry, yes. The machine is on a domain, and I searched the registry, search the file system itself (in hopes there was a shortcut), and I looked at the properties of the shortcuts that were displayed in the file tree on the left side of the Save As dialog to make sure none of them pointed to the old PC.